# How to change column values in for loops with IF condition

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new at Google Apps Script. I have an array where I need to change the values in column 7 (gci) to the values in column 6 (referalcomm) IF the value in column 5 (referral) == ABC. This is the script:

```
function netincome() {
  var report = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = report.getSheetByName("Test");
  var dataRange = data.getDataRange();
  var lastrow = dataRange.getLastRow();
  
  var gci = data.getRange(1, 7, lastrow, 1).getValues ();
  var referral = data.getRange(1, 5, lastrow, 1).getValues();
  var referralcomm = data.getRange(1, 6, lastrow, 1).getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i<=lastrow; i ++) {
     if (referral == "ABC") { 
       gci.setValue(referralcomm);
     }
  }
}
```

But, the script does not change the value of Col 7 to the one in Col 6 when Col 5 == ABC.
Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function netincome() {
  var report = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var data = report.getSheetByName("Test");
  var dataRange = data.getDataRange();
  var lastrow = dataRange.getLastRow();
  
  var gci = data.getRange(1, 7, lastrow, 1).getValues ();
  var referral = data.getRange(1, 5, lastrow, 1).getValues();
  var referralcomm = data.getRange(1, 6, lastrow, 1).getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<lastrow;i++) {
     if (referral[i][0] == "ABC") { 
       gci[i][0]=referralcomm[i][0]);
     }
  }
  data.getRange(1, 7, lastrow, 1).setValues(gci);
}
```

I think this is the same thing

```
function netincome() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh==ss.getSheetByName('Test');
  var vs=sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var or=sh.getRange(1,7,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  var ov=oR.getValues();
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(r[4]=="ABC") {
      oA[i][0]=r[5];
    }
  });
  or.setValues(ov);
}
```

Comment: Option 1 returns an error "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" for the line "if (referral[i][0] == "ABC") {".

Option 2 worked beautifully - Thank you!!
(correcting for a couple of typos == to =, oR to or, and oA to ov)